# Ubuntu 18.04 - Dock won't appear when moused over when VLC is in fullscreen

Tags: mouse, vlc, gnome-shell, fullscreen, ubuntu-dock

After upgrading Ubuntu to 18.04, I noticed that I could no longer mouse over the dock and have it appear if I was playing a video in VLC in full-screen. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and run the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide-in-fullscreen 'true'
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: on ubuntu 20 with wayland this option is not workign for me